# Choose XSL transform acoording to document content

Tags: xslt

I have a large number of XHTML documents which are created by different publishers, determined by a `meta` tag:

`<meta name="citation_publisher" content="ACME publisher"/>`

or in a different document

`<meta name="citation_publisher" content="BETA publisher"/>`

etc.
I have written stylesheets (about 1 page each) such as,

```
acme.xsl
beta.xsl
```

etc.
However I do not know the name of the publisher until I read the XHTML file.

It is possible, though very messy, to write a gigantic stylesheet of the form:

```xsl
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$publisher='ACME publisher'">
    <!-- acme.xsl sheet-->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$publisher='BETA publisher'">
    <!-- beta.xsl sheet-->
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

but there are at least 100 XSL files.
Is there any way, in XSL1, to select the stylesheet chunk according to the publisher? It would be nice to have the stylesheets as separate files and `<xsl:import>` them rather than have a single huge file.

UPDATE:
I think @Dimitre has answered the question correctly (and so I have accepted). I suspect that @MichaelKay's is actually better , but it does depend on having a pipeline managing the transformer. I shall try the `<xsl:include>` as a prototype and see whether it has downsides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but there are at least 100 XSL files. Is there any way, in XSL1, to
>   select the stylesheet chunk according to the publisher? It would be
>   nice to have the stylesheets as separate files and `<xsl:import>` them
>   rather than have a single huge file.

**Here is one way to do this** (I am showing working just with two content publisher types and this can be done for as many as needed):

Primary stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:import href="unknown.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="acme.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="beta.xsl"/>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

acme.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*[meta[@content='ACME publisher']]">
    <xsl:value-of select="x * y"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

beta.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*[meta[@content='BETA publisher']]">
    <xsl:value-of select="x + y"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

unknown.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">Error: Unknown content source</xsl:message>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the transformation specified in the primary stylesheet is applied on this XML document**:

acme.xml:

```
<t>
  <meta name="citation_publisher" content="ACME publisher"/>
  <x>6</x>
  <y>4</y>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result** (`x*y`) **is produced**:

```
24
```

**When the same transformation is applied on this XML document**:

beta.xml:

```
<t>
  <meta name="citation_publisher" content="BETA publisher"/>
  <x>6</x>
  <y>4</y>
</t>
```

**again the correct result** (`x+y`) **is produced**:

10

**Finally, when the same transformation is applied on this XML document:**

other.xml:

```
<t>
  <meta name="citation_publisher" content="OTHER publisher"/>
  <x>6</x>
  <y>4</y>
</t>
```

**the result of the transformation is the wanted termination with error message**:

```
Error: Unknown content source
Processing terminated by xsl:message at line 5
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't attempt to do this within a single XSLT stylesheet. It sounds to me like a good candidate for XProc, or some similar pipeline technology (e.g. Orbeon). Step 1, use XPath to classify the document, Step 2, transform it using the stylesheet chosen according to the results of Step 1.